# Perforce: Prevent keywords from being expanded when syncing files out of the depot?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have a situation where I'd like to diff two branches in Perforce. Normally I'd use `diff2` to do a server-side diff but in this case the files on the branches are so large that the `diff2` call ends up filling up `/tmp` on my server trying to diff them and the diff fails.

I can't bring down my server to rectify this so I'm looking at checking out the the content to disk and using `diff` on the command line to inspect and compare the content.

The trouble is: most of the files have RCS keywords in them that are being expanded.

I know can remove keyword expansion from a file by opening the files for edit and removing the `-k` attribute from the files in the process, but that seems a bit brute force. I was hoping I could just tell the `p4 sync` command not to expand the keywords on checkout. I can't seem to find a way to do this? Is it possible?

As a possible alternative solution, does anyone know if you can tell `p4 diff2` which directory to use for temporary space when you call it? If I could tell it to use abundant NAS space instead of `/tmp` on the Perforce server I might be able to make it work.

I'm using 2010.x version of Perforce if that changes the answer in any way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way I know of to disable keyword expansion on sync. Here's what I would try:

1) Create a branch spec between the two sets of files
2) Run "p4 files //path/to/files/... | cut -d '#' -f 1 > tmp"

Path to files above should be the right hand side of the branch spec you created

3) p4 -x tmp diff2 -b

This tells p4 to iterate over the lines of text in 'tmp' and treat them as arguments to the command. I think /tmp on your server will get cleared in-between each file this way, preventing it from filling up.

I unfortunately don't have files large enough to test that it works, so this is entirely theoretical.

To change the temp directory that p4d uses just TEMP or TMP to a different path and restart p4d. If you're on Windows make sure to call 'p4 set -S perforce TMP=' to set variable for the Perforce service; without the -S perforce you'll just set it for the current user.

Comment: Yea, you're confirming what I thought was true on the keyword expansion. Unfortunately diff2 blows up for a bunch of the files. There are some massive files in the repository that are pure text. Like 500+ GB files. And it's on those that diff2 chokes every time. I updated the question though -- maybe I can steer `diff2` around `/tmp`?